# Call a function inside an OpenMP for loop

Tags: c++, c, multithreading, openmp

Just getting started with OpenMP. I was wondering if it's possible to run an OpenMP parallel for in a for loop that calls an external function, that in itself doesn't call any other function. I've put in some simplifed code to make my point:

```
#pragma omp parallel for
for(span=0;span<info.nospanelement;span++)
{
    some_function(info,wakePtr[time][span],P,w_ind,1);

    //additions to be done each repeat
    w_wake[0] += w_ind[0];
    w_wake[1] += w_ind[1];
    w_wake[2] += w_ind[2];
}
```

I know I need to add some more to the call, but can this openMp loop technically work?

Comment: "and i'm getting some errors" what errors?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must **never** have different threads write the same variables without proper synchronization that avoids **race conditions**.

In your program, several threads **read the same value** of a variable, then each one adds another value to it, then **all of them write the result in the same location**, so that many calculations get overwritten and don't add up to the final result. Because of this, the results calculated by your program are lower than the correct values (by the way, **you should have stated exactly how the result of your program was different from what you expected**).

A simple but inefficient workaround is to use atomic additions:

```
#pragma omp parallel for
    for(span=0;span<info.nospanelement;span++) {
        some_function(info,wakePtr[time][span],P,w_ind,1);

        //additions to be done each repeat
#pragma omp atomic
    w_wake[0] += w_ind[0];
#pragma omp atomic
    w_wake[1] += w_ind[1];
#pragma omp atomic
    w_wake[2] += w_ind[2];
}
```

A more efficient way to sum in parallel is to have each thread accumulate values in a private variable (only seen by that thread), thus obtaining partial sums.

```
#pragma omp parallel 
{
    int wake0 = wake1 = wake2 = 0; // private variables

    #pragma omp for
    for(span=0;span<info.nospanelement;span++)
    {
        some_function(info,wakePtr[time][span],P,w_ind,1);

        //additions to be done each repeat
        wake0 += w_ind[0];  // accumulate in private variable
        wake1 += w_ind[1];
        wake2 += w_ind[2];
    }
// now we're out of the loop but still inside the parallel region
// so, let's add up the partial sums
#pragma omp atomic
    w_wake[0] += wake0;
#pragma omp atomic
    w_wake[1] += wake1;
#pragma omp atomic
    w_wake[2] += wake2;
}
```

It's usually better to have OpenMP manage the reduction operations, but but if you need to store the results in an array it is probably easier to just do it yourself this way.

On the other hand, if you don't really need an array then you can simply do this:

```
int wake0 = wake1 = wake2 = 0; // SHARED variables this time
#pragma omp parallel for reduction(+ : wake0, wake1, wake2)
{
    for(span=0;span<info.nospanelement;span++)
    {
        some_function(info,wakePtr[time][span],P,w_ind,1);

        //additions to be done each repeat
        wake0 += w_ind[0];  // accumulate in private variable
        wake1 += w_ind[1];
        wake2 += w_ind[2];
    }
}
```

Comment: My OpenMP is very rusty. Can't you do `#pragma omp parallel for reduction(+ : w_wake[0], w_wake[1], w_wake[2])`?

Comment: @RafaelLerm I thought so, but then I googled about performing reduction on arrays, and for some reason OpenMP cannot do that -except in Fortran, starting at OpenMP 3.0, and with a very good compiler-. Or maybe you can do it using the syntax you just quoted, I can't be sure without trying.

Comment: Ok. This reminds me of all my rage about only Fortran having the `max` and `min` reductions...

Comment: @RafaelLerm - since OpenMP 3.1, `max` and `min` reductions are available for C/C++ as well; and since OpenMP 4.0, there are user-defined reductions.

Comment: @AlexeyKukanov You just made me happy and embarrassed at the same time. Thank you very much for that information, I'll look into it.

Comment: OpenMP for Fortran supports array reductions starting from version 2.0.

Comment: @AlexeyKukanov Then you see what the statement "my OpenMP is rusty" really means... but I'm glad to know things have made progress.

Comment: Thank you! Sorry I cannot give a specific number or issue. This software is for potential flow code (like CFD); it's open source, called FreeWake. The errors were different values of lift, drag, cd, cm, etc. a whole mess really. This fixed a few things, thanks again!